# Delete lines with reocurrences

Tags: bash, shell

how do I change a text file so it erases only the lines which have the same word?

example:

1. blue green yellow
2. red orange brown
3. violet pink green

desired output

1. blue green yellow
2. red orange brown

because of finding the word green, the line was erased

Comment: So if any of the words in previous lines is found in a line, it has to be deleted?

Comment: how about a line: `foo bar foo` remove or keep? and how big is your real input file?

Comment: input file is a text file with several lines each with about 30 characters. it has random words and the description fedorqui gave is perfect. That's what I want

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'my $p=1;@w=split;for(@w){$p=0 if $w{$_}}print if $p;$w{$_}=1 for(@w)' file
```

Trick: I'm using both an array `@w` for the words of the current line, and a hash `%w` for all words encountered in previous lines. `$p` is used to indicate printing is necessary.

This will print `foo bar foo`.
A version that doesn't, is even easier, but it's left as an exercise to the OP. :-)

Comment: You are a wizard! can you do the same with the functions "grep" or "sort"? 

Because I don't understand perl all that well... I think you're using perl in the very shell. I might be very wrong in what I'm saying but if so, could you please use just the shell commands such as grep, sort etc? just bash programming 

I'm sorry I wasn't specific at first and I'm very thankful for your answer

Comment: I'm sure it's possible with the shell tools, but it´s sooooo much easier with a Perl oneliner. And apart from a few embedded systems, Perl is available everywhere. I even have it on my router.

Comment: thank you a lot for you input. you definitely showed something I didn't know. I'll try to invest on perl then.

Comment: Actually `awk` is a shell tool that has associative arrays, the key to the solution. But I don't know it so well.